# transition between ViewControllers not animating correct VC

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller

So I'm trying to animate the tractions between my UIViewControllers. I want the new VC to push in from the same side that the button is located on. I have managed to push in one VC from the right, but when I try to push in from the left it will push in the same VC first then the new VC pops up.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    switch sender.view {
    case settingsButton:
        let settingScreen = SettingsVC()
        settingScreen.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(settingScreen, animated: false, completion: nil)
        let transition      = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.7
        transition.type     = .moveIn
        transition.subtype  = .fromLeft
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .default)
        view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    case calendarButton:
        let calendarScreen  = CalendarVC()
        calendarScreen.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(calendarScreen, animated: false, completion: nil)
        let transition      = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.5
        transition.type     = .moveIn
        transition.subtype  = .fromRight
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    default:
        break
    }
```

Comment: Will I need to have a navigation controller to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using CATransition to achieve this. With that, you can animate view transitions, within a single UIViewController. UIViewController transitions are a bit different.

Apple has it's own API for UIViewController transitions, but it's very cumbersome.

The best solution, in my opinion, is to use [Hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero) library from Github.
It doesn't have a steep learning curve, and this kind of simple animations can be easily achieved.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying out hero now. Do I need to use a navigation controller for this?

Comment: You do not. You can specify animation when presenting the VC modally

Comment: So i should be able to just go into each VC and specify the animation I want with hero?

Comment: Yes, try it out and see.